# Is there a way to stop objects visually "clipping" through others at a distance?

Tags: 3d-view

[image]

Up close, they don't clip through each other, but the farther out you zoom the more they do.

Comment: z fighting of overlapping geometry... no solution I'm aware of. Z fighting is due to calculation approximations (limits) that cannot be avoid.

Comment: Reduce the clip range, to  a reasonable max/min difference, for floating point to handle in the viewport. On a _camera_, say you have a huge long shot going to an extreme close-up, you can key-frame the range, for renders.

Answer (score 2):

Increase the viewport **Clip Start** value, found at the top right of the viewport in the screenshot.

If the start is really low or the end is really high it can cause issues like you see. Try 100mm (the default) and that should help.

I don't know the technical reasons for this issue, but a really small start value or a really large end value can cause the issue you're seeing.

Comment: The depth buffer has a limited resolution. If the clip distance encompasses a large distance, then blender cannot distinguish between surfaces that are close together. Usually you want the clip distance to be that of the scene, but no more. Having a clip range that is much larger than the scene will just result in lack of precision.

Comment: Z Fighting applies to surfaces that are close together, but also to those that fall below the precision of the depth buffer.